# Working with images in Perl 6

Tags: raku

I want to be able to edit an image in Perl 6. I've googled but haven't found anything. Are there any libraries such as PIL for Python?

Comment: You can interop with most Perl or Python libraries if you install the associated Inline module. You can also use Nativecall to easily make a wrapper for any library with a C interface.

Comment: @BradGilbert, so there're no libraries?

Comment: you can try this perl6 library https://github.com/mrhdias/perl6-Imlib2 which seems its in status WIP ,also you can look at https://modules.perl6.org/ for modules that start with Image:: , or as Brad said you can use Inline::Perl or inline::Python to use Perl 5 or Python modules from Perl 6